# Installing lirc_rpi on raspbmc with updated kernel

Tags: debian, raspbmc

I accidentally broke my raspbmc distro by running `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, and managed to get it back to a useable state by running `rpi-update` manually on the SD card on a PC, however now because of the kernel differences I'm without the `lirc_rpi` module. Is there an easy way I can get it back - either by manually using the old kernel (but with XBMC and the rest still working) or by getting a new version for the new kernel?

Comment: I think I just solved it by giving up and reinstalling from scratch. This was a rather old problem, when Raspbmc was in beta or release candidate and not the final version.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Raspbmc with lirc_pi and TSOPxxxx IR receiver connected to GPIO and there have been three automatic updates including a kernel upgragde it still works normally without any change needed.
I suggest following

- Get a backup of your current settings by XBMC backup add-on.
- Flash sd card manually with last known good version of Raspbmc where your lirc_pi was working fine.
- Check if lirc_pi module is working as you expect.
- Let auto update take its cource, you will be at latest release after a few update/reboot cycles with your lirc_pi intact and working fine.